# SQL elegance: Can this subselect be avoided?

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a SQL statement where the subselect where clause is very similar to the outer where claus.  It makes me wonder if there's a cleaner way to express it.

The data receives updates every month and each line of data gets a start date when it appeared and an end date when it no longer appears.  It may either no longer appear due to the line of data completely going away or from the line of data changing at all.  Any given id may have 1 or multiple lines of data.  My inner select finds all IDs where any of the lines have recently changed/been removed and the outer select finds all lines with those IDs that are either current or have recently changed/been removed.  This is running in Netezza.

```
select A.*, Case when current='Y' then (case when start_date='20190101' then 'NEW' else 'Is' end) else 'Gone' end as status
from DataSource A
join (
select A.ID from IDsOfInterest A join DataSource B on A.ID=B.ID
where (current='Y' and start_date='20190101') or end_date='20190101'
group by a.id
) B on A.ID=B.ID
where (current='Y') or end_date='20190101'

per comment, sample data. Assume ID 1 exists in table IDsOfInterest:
Table DataSource:
ID, current, start_date, end_date, data, note
1, 'N', 20180101, 20180201, A, Disappears
1, 'N', 20180101, 20180201, B, Changes
1, 'Y', 20180201, 99991231, B, Changed
1, 'N', 20180101, 20190101, C, Recently Gone
1, 'Y', 20180101, 99991231, D, Always there
1, 'N', 20180101, 20190101, E, Recently Changes
1, 'Y', 20190101, 99991231, E, Recently Changed

Query results:
1, 'Y', 20180201, 99991231, B, Changed, Is
1, 'N', 20180101, 20190101, C, Recently Gone, Gone
1, 'Y', 20180101, 99991231, D, Always there, Is
1, 'N', 20180101, 20190101, E, Recently Changes, Gone
1, 'Y', 20190101, 99991231, E, Recently Changed, NEW
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help others undersand what this should be doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `with` you can query your data once with the filters in where clause

The code is more cleaner and you'll get a performance benefit because instead of two passes on the DataSource table you are reading once.

```
with A as (
  select * from DataSource 
   where (current='Y' and start_date='20190101') or end_date='20190101'))
select A.*, Case when current='Y' then (case when start_date='20190101' 
               then 'NEW' else 'Is' end) else 'Gone' end as status
  from A
  join (
select I.ID from IDsOfInterest I join A on I.ID=A.ID
 group by a.id 
) B on A.ID=B.ID
where current='Y' or end_date='20190101'
```

We also can move your join to get IDs into a filter and that will be faster than join

```
with A as (
  select * from DataSource 
   where (current='Y' and start_date='20190101') or end_date='20190101'))
select A.*, Case when current='Y' then (case when start_date='20190101' 
               then 'NEW' else 'Is' end) else 'Gone' end as status
 from A
where current='Y' or end_date='20190101'
  and ID in (select distinct I.ID from IDsOfInterest I join A on I.ID=A.ID)
```

Please let me know if this helps

Comment: Well, both of your statements still have the similar-looking where statements in them, but I'm not sure there's any way to avoid that without things getting convoluted.  I like how you addressed performance stuff